# How to get Alt-Gr keys for Euro and Pound symbols working on Apple Magic Keyboard under Ubuntu 20.04 (GNOME desktop)

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-20.04, gnome, keyboard-layout

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME desktop, and recently I started using an Apple Magic Keyboard (model A1644, international 79-key QWERTY version, with Euro and Pound symbols added to 2- and 3-keys).

After some initial tweaks (see below), everything now *almost* works as it should. Almost, because pressing Alt-Gr + 2 or Alt-Gr + 3 doesn't produce a Euro or Pound symbol, respectively, but just 2 or 3.

What I already tried:

- Created a file `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` with the line `options hid_apple fnmode=2 iso_layout=0` to get the function keys to behave as such without pressing the fn-key and to get the ~/` key working (see e.g. here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard or https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Apple_Keyboard). This worked. The reason that I'm mentioning this anyway is because I'm not sure whether this influences any of the other things I tried (the Euro and Pound symbols also didn't work before this change, but still)
- Choosing different keyboard layout under settings (GUI)
- Editing `/etc/default/keyboard` (see e.g. here: https://www.unixfu.ch/using-apple-mac-keyboard-with-ubuntu/, or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302185/missing-apple-keyboard-layout-english-international-macintosh, or https://askubuntu.com/questions/843590/key-keycode-49-and-key-keycode-94-are-inverted-on-macbookpro-keyboar/844931#844931)
- To help with the above, I checked the available settings/options in `xorg.lst` (overwhelming!)

I did manage to get my right Alt-key to behave as Alt-Gr (at least I hope; it stopped behaving as an Alt-key in any case), but so far I'm still unable to produce Euro or Pound symbols.

I'd greatly appreciate any help to resolve this!

EDIT:
Output of `setxkbmap -query -v 10` (after returning everything except the Alt-key back to its original value):

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
options:    lv3:ralt_switch
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+us:2+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
options:    lv3:ralt_switch
```